# IE not printing disabled radio button's selection

Tags: asp.net, web, internet-explorer-8

I have a set of radio buttons that are all disabled, and one of them is selected.  In IE8, when I print the web page, the selected radio button is not showing as selected.  However, this works fine in FireFox.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the selection and disabling being made into html tag or via javascript?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem. Could you please provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, we had some javascript that was manipulating the radio buttons after page load, and that was causing the issue.  I find it interesting that the issue only manifested in print mode, though.